# Is it Possible to animate spinner dropdown?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-spinner

how is it possible to animate spinner dropdown?? because i apply animation to spinner but it applied to spinner not to spinner dropdown and my spinner is animated. 
Can i animate spinner dropdown or it impossible.
please suggest me right answer

Comment: have you got any solution to your question

Comment: no i haven't got any solution

Comment: Can you get animation only for opening spinner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible! I tried to do the same but all in vain. In my case i wanted to slow down the speed of dropdown by applying slide down animation but instead my spinner got animated. I did a lot of research on google too but nothing helped. Alas! i concluded that spinner has very limited properties and we can't really do anything about that.